# Java: Question on assert-behaviour

Tags: java, assert

I have this code snippet

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AssertTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        assert(list.add("test")); //<-- adds an element

        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Why is the output list empty? How does assert behave here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes, it does. I just activated the -ea flag and it outputs 1.

Comment: ok - `add()` returns a boolean. something I didn't know and I still don't want to know. such return type is just silly. if a subtype of `Collection` needs to provide such function, the subtype can add a new method.

Comment: The fact that `add()` returns a boolean might be useful when using `HashSet<?>`. If you try to add a value having the same hash code as one contained in the set, the `add()` method will return false. You can also think of `Collection<?>`s allowing only `n` values. So the return value is fully justified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enable assertion with -ea flag... such as;

```
java -ea -cp . AssertTest
```

Also using assertion is worst place for side effects..

Comment: plus, never use the side-effects of assert expressions in your application!

Answer (score 5):

Never assert on anything with side effects. When you run without asserts enabled (enabled with `-ea`), `list.add("test")` will not be executed.

It's a good habit to never assert anything but false, as follows:

```
if (!list.add("test")) {
  assert false;
  // Handle the problem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assertions needs to be enabled. Enable them using the -ea switch.

See [the Java application launcher docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable assert. ie run as **java -ea AssertTest**

Answer (score 0):

Incidental to your question - assertions should not contain code that is needed for the correct operation of your program, since this causes that correct operation to be dependent on whether assertions are enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

assert method that checks whether a Boolean expression is true or false. If the expression evaluates to true, then there is no effect. But if it evaluates to false, the assert method prints the stack trace and the program aborts. In this sample implementation, a second argument for a string is used so that the cause of error can be printed.